# Why coluldnot my installer to remove start menu item?

Tags: nsis

My installer uninstall.exe is unable to remove start menu entry.Below has some part of code code can any one tell me where i am wrong.

```
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_ROOT HKLM
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_KEY ${REGKEY}
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_VALUENAME StartMenuGroup
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_DEFAULTFOLDER "IREC "


 !insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_WRITE_BEGIN Application



 CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}\$startmenufolder"
 CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}\$startmenufolder\$(^Name).lnk" "$INSTDIR\eclipse\iREC.exe" 
 CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}\$startmenufolder\Uninstall $(^Name).lnk" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"

    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\eclipse"
    CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\$(^Name).lnk" "$INSTDIR\eclipse\iREC.exe" 

    !insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_WRITE_END


DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$registry"
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}\$startmenufolder\Uninstall $(^Name).lnk"
Delete  "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}\$startmenufolder\$(^Name).lnk"
```

Comment: Only posting the part of the code **you** think is relevant only makes it harder to debug the problem, if you don't want to share all of it you can create a simple example with the same issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Are you using [MUI_STARTMENU_GETFOLDER](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Examples/Modern%20UI/StartMenu.nsi) to initialize $startmenufolder in the uninstaller?
- Do you have `RequestExecutionLevel` in your script to [avoid stupid compatibility stuff](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Shortcuts_removal_fails_on_Windows_Vista)?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using [SetShellVarContext](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/SetShellVarContext)?